# Sum of horizontal lifts

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle with a connection. Let $v\in T_pM$ and $v^e$ be its horizontal lift to $e\in\pi^{-1}(\{p\})$. If $e_1,e_2\in\pi^{-1}(\{p\})$ then I want to show that $v^{e_1+e_2}=v^{e_1}+_*v^{e_2}$ where $+_*$ is the pushforward of the addition map $+:E\times E\to E$ on the fibers.

By uniqueness of horizontal lifts, I need to show that $\pi_*(v^{e_1}+_*v^{e_2})(f)=v(f)$ for any smooth function $f$ on $M$. What I get is

$
\begin{align*}
\pi_*(v^{e_1}+_*v^{e_2})(f)&=(v^{e_1}+_*v^{e_2})(f\circ\pi) \\
&=(v^{e_1},v^{e_2})(f\circ\pi\circ+) \\
&=v^{e_1}(f\circ\pi\circ+\vert_{\pi^{-1}(\{p\})\times\{e_2\}})+v^{e_2}(f\circ\pi\circ+\vert_{\{e_1\}\times\pi^{-1}(\{p\})}) \\
&=v^{e_1}(f\circ\pi)+v^{e_2}(f\circ\pi) \\
&=v(f)+v(f) \\
&=2v(f).
\end{align*}
$

The 4th line is from the fact that restriction of the addition map sends points to the same fiber. My answer results in a factor of $2$ that shouldn't be there but I cannot figure out what went wrong, although I suspect that the 3rd line is the culprit. I appreciate any help.

Comment: The lifts $v^{e_{i}} \in T_{e_{i}}E$ aren't based at the same point of $E$. Are you sure you're not trying to show $(v + w)^{e} = v^{e} + w^{e}$ (i.e., that horizontal lifting respects addition) or something of that type...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I got this from part of exercise 12.30 in "Manifolds and Differential Geometry" although the problem is not identical. I wrote the question based on what I thought the problem would have been. I don't believe that it's the question you referred to though.

Comment: @user375366: Note that there is no addition map $+ \colon E \times E \rightarrow E$ because you cannot add two vectors based at different points. Rather, you have a map $+ \colon E \times_{\pi} E \rightarrow E$ (over $\pi$) between the fibered product $E \times_{\pi} E$ whose fiber over a point $p \in M$ is $E_p \times E_p$ to $E$. The way the question is phrased right now, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @levap Isn't each fiber $\pi^{-1}(\{p\})$ a vector space so addition is defined on the fibers? I haven't encountered fibered products before so I am a bit lost there.

Comment: Each fiber is a vector space but the horizontal vectors (unlike the vertical vectors) are tangent vectors in $TE$ that "point away" from the fibers. For vertical vectors in $TE$, you can restrict the addition to a map $T \colon E_p \times E_p \rightarrow E_p$ and then ask what is $dT|_{u_1,u_2}(v,w)$ for tangent vectors $v \in T_(u_1)(E_p), w \in T_{u_2}(E_p)$ but those vectors are tangent to the fibers.

Comment: @levap Right, I think I understand what you're saying. Horizontal vectors cannot be generated by curves lying in $E_p$ so the pushforward (under addition) doesn't make sense for horizontal vectors. I'll have to rethink my question.

Comment: @user375366: This is precisely why it is delicate to define a "linear" connection on a vector bundle in terms of the horizontal distribution. If you allow arbitrary horizontal distributions, you will get a non-linear parallel transport but to write down the precise conditions which will give you a linear parallel transport is awkward. It is done much more elegantly using a principal bundle or a covariant derivative formulation.